# Angular build SyntaxError: invalid regexp group

Tags: angular, docker

I was building my angular project with docker and Nginx but when I try to run the image it works on Chrome only. The other browsers are complaining `SyntaxError: invalid regexp group`. There are not many details and I did not use any regex in my development.

I tried researching online but could not come across any helpful resources.

Wondering if anyone came across this issue?[image: rejx]

Comment: the only clue you have is hammerjs... Maybe your version of hammerjs does not support you typescript/angular version... ?

Comment: hmmm but I am able to start the project with npm start.

Comment: @Random I resolved the hammerjs but it still has the same problem

Comment: Have you enable the prod mod ? Can you set `sourcemap: true` in your configuration so you may be able to see which file is causing this error (instead of vendor.js)

Comment: I'm faceing the same error .. larger angular project  doesn't work in dev or prod mode in firefox - chrome/edge/safari are fine..